The $K_1$-group of integer valued polynomials
Let $R=$ Int$(\mathbb{Z}) = \{f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]| f(\mathbb{Z}) \subset \mathbb{Z}\}$. I am interested to find $K_1(R)$. I list my trials below:
Let us construct a Milnor square $$\matrix{R&\rightarrow&R_m\cr
             \downarrow&&\downarrow\cr
              R/m&\rightarrow&R_m/mR_m}$$
Now I have an exact sequence $K_1(R) \rightarrow K_1(R_m) \oplus K_1(R/m) \rightarrow K_1(R_m/mR_m) \rightarrow ....$ But after this I am unable to progress. I could also not determine a suitable commutator of $GL_n(R)$. One thing that I know is that $R_p$ is a valuation ring for every prime ideal $p$, but I am unable to use it anywhere. I would be grateful for any suggestions or hints. Thank you.

So since any element can be written as a finite $\mathbb{Z}$ linear combination of binomial polynomials they have a presentation as \mathbb{Z}[x]?
